# How can I solve Attribute Error in Binary Search Tree Insertion?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm studying BST and have reached a problem within this topic.

This is all of the code.

```
class Node:
    # elem is element of Node.
    def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None, parent=None, elem=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.key = key
        self.elem = elem

    # External Node Check 
    def isExternal(node):
        if (node.left is None) and (node.right is None):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    # Internal Node Check
    def isInternal(node):
        if (node.left is not None) and (node.right is not None):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def expandExternal(z):
        leftnode = Node()
        rightnode = Node()
        leftnode.left = None
        leftnode.right = None
        leftnode.parent = z
        rightnode.left = None
        rightnode.right = None
        rightnode.parent = z
        z.left = leftnode
        z.right = rightnode
        return
    
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insertItem(self, key, elem):
        node = self.treeSearch(self.root, key)
        if Node.isInternal(node):
            return
        node.elem = elem
        node.key = key
        Node.expandExternal(node)
        return
    
    def treeSearch(self, node, key):
        if Node.isExternal(node):
            return node
        if key == node.key:
            return node
        elif key < node.key:
            return self.treeSearch(node.left, key)
        else:
            return self.treeSearch(node.right, key)

def main():
    n=int(input("ENTER THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS: \n"))

    b=BST()

    for i in range (n):
        print("\nENTER THE DETAILS OF STUDENT ",i+1,":")
        key=int(input("Enter the roll num:        "))
        name=input("Enter name:        ")
        b.insertItem(key, name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**then Error is
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'**

The error occurs in this part:

```
    def isExternal(node):
        if (node.left == None) & (node.right == None): # <-- error here
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What is wrong with this code?

I wanted to put the roll number as the key and the name as the element and insert them, however I couldn't.

Comment: `&` is not the same as `and`; don't use it.

Comment: You are using what should be an instance method as a regular function, which means you can (and are) making a call `isExternal` with `None`, not an instance of `Node`, as an argument.

Comment: That is, `node.isExternal()`, not `Node.isExternal(node)`, etc.

Comment: And comparisons to `None` should always be made with `is` and `is not`, not `==` and `!=`.

Comment: Typically, you don't bother doing a full search when trying to insert. Just try to insert it where it belongs, and if the slot is already occupied, don't make an assignment.